# how can I get the value of variable in another file (FLASK)

Tags: python, file, flask, import

I have an app.py file and I want to call a variable in a config file located in the same folder.

I have already tried to import the file but it doesn't recognize it

This is my app.py file

```py
def ldap_connect(data):
   try:
       server = ldap.initialize(app.config['IP_ldap'])
```

this is my config.py file (located in the same folder)

```py
# coding=utf-8

####CONFIG LDAP####
IP_ldap = "ldap://127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the content of your file in app.py with :

```
from config import *
```

and then :

```
app.config['IP_ldap'] = IP_ldap
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `import` will do the trick:

```
from config import IP_ldap

def ldap_connect(data):
   try:
       server = ldap.initialize(IP_ldap)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from config.py import IP_ldap
```

if it does't work,

maybe you need add file **init**.py